# Where to find myPersonality Dataset?

Tags: data-request

MyPersonality Project is a Facebook application used to predict personality based on an online questionnaire. Dataset consists of status updates from 250 users, which already labeled into Big Five personality dimensions. All posts from single user ID appended into one long string which considered single document. Final dataset is in the form of 250 documents from 250 users.

I want to build multi-label classification model on this dataset , but cannot find the dataset . Please help..

Comment: did you ask facebook? why do you think a facebook app is open, let alone open data? can we have some links to reference this please?

Answer (score 2):

According to what mentioned form the project owner that in 2018, they decided to stop sharing the data with other scholars. Maintaining the data set, vetting the projects, responding to the inquiries, and complying with various regulations has become too burdensome for the two authors. Therefore, they decided to no further share this psychological data with other interested researchers. Source: https://sites.google.com/michalkosinski.com/mypersonality